# What are ping packets made of?

Tags: dhcp, tcpip, ping, protocol, packet

What exactly are in the packets that are sent via the `ping` command?

I was reading a Wikipedia article about magic numbers and saw this:

> DHCP packets use a "magic cookie" value of '63  82 53 63' at the start of the options  section of the packet. This value is included in all DHCP packet types.

so what else is in the packets?

Comment: "What is in a packet" is much too broad of a question to answer here. It involves a knowledge of Layer 2 and 3 technologies that is much too long for an answer here. There are entire college courses on the topic. I would suggest reading the wikipedia article that you quoted and googling any terms that you don't understand and go from there.

Comment: I just want to know what code (hexadecimal I assume?) is in it.

Comment: ping packets are made of ones and zeroes (1's and 0's), just like all other packets.

Comment: @quack: Yes, I know that, I just wanted something a level or two  higher than binary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ping`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping) packets are ICMP packets (IP protocol number 1) with a subtype of ECHO REQUEST or ECHO REPLY.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do some more research on ECHO REQUEST and ECHO REPLY.

Comment: technically *ping* is ECHO REQUEST.  ECHO REPLY is one type of *ack*.  ping! ack. ping! ack. ping! ack.

Answer (score 2):

Get Wireshark(previously called Ethereal), a packet sniffer, and have a look what binary/hex is in there.